# javaee-endorsed-api-7.0 not found

Tags: java, netbeans-8

Good morning the reason for my question is about an error that tells me neatbens **javaee-endorsed-api-7.0 not found** I'm trying to find information on how to solve but I find information is 6.0 but it works for me can someone tell me how solve this problem or provide information where you can find information I am creating a web project with **java web jee 7** the version of the neatbens is 8.2

> I am working an application web project

```js
< target name = "-init-taskdefs" >
  <
  fail unless = "libs.CopyLibs.classpath" >
  The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
This property must point to
org - netbeans - modules - java - j2seproject - copylibstask.jar file which is part of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at &
  lt;
netbeans_installation & gt;
/java&lt;version&gt;/ant / extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually.For example like this:
  ant - Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath = a / path / to / org - netbeans - modules - java - j2seproject - copylibstask.jar <
  /fail> <
  taskdef classpath = "${libs.CopyLibs.classpath}"
resource = "org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml" / >
  <
  /target>
```

**error**

> ant -f "G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb" -Dnb.internal.action.name=build -DforceRedeploy=false "-Dbrowser.context=G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb" dist
>   G:\Mis Documentos\NetBeansProjects\WebServiceSicb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:797: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
>   This property must point to 
>   org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
>   of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at 
>   /java/ant/extra folder.
>   Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
>   exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:
>    ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
>
> Blockquote

Comment: http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/81cat-Missing-Library-javaee-endorsed-api-7-0-td5745721.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a lack of information in your post please add more details, else if you're working in a maven project add this block to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

else download the jar file and add it to your classpath: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaeeendorsedapi70jar.htm

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem. Just go to Tools--> Plugin-->Available Plugins---> Search for EJB and Ear and install it. The problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in NetBeans by clicking the "clean and build" option. A popup appeared and I clicked 'update'.